# Getting started with Spring 3 Web MVC - Setting everything up

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get started with JAVA/Eclipse/Spring MVC but can't seem to find a "dummies" or "step-by-step" guide for setting everything up and creating the simplest proof-of-concept application.

I found http://static.springsource.org/docs/...-step-by-step/ but there seem to be differences between Spring 2.5 and Spring 3 so i'm looking for something for Spring 3.

Also, the tutorial for Spring 2.5 focuses on building the application usign Ant - This i will certainly be doing for releasing but when working within Eclipse i want to have set up the project so that i can use breakpoints/debugging and this is not covered at all.

I've downloaded Eclipse, Tomcat and the Spring 3 Framework but that's about it and within the downloaded Spring Framework documentation it states:

> 2.3 New getting started tutorial
>
> There is now a new getting started tutorial
> for developing a basic Spring 3.0 MVC
> web application. This tutorial is a
> separate document that can be found at
> the [Spring Documentation page](http://www.springsource.org/documentation)

However, i can't seem to find such a tutorial on the linked page. My main problem at the moment, as seems to be the case for many people trying to get started with Spring, is that i can't seem to get everything set up.

I've got a copy of [Expert Spring MVC and Web Flow](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059584X) and i've also found [this tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html) but i don't know if the setups they describe are still relevant and whether they will allow debugging.

Can anyone please give some direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Get the [*mvc-basic*](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk) or the [*petcare*](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petcare/trunk) sample apps from the [Spring Samples SVN repository](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/). These samples have been updated to Spring 3.0 and are directly importable & runnable with [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts).

Comment: Also opens/runs no problems in NetBeans as they're maven projects. There's no reason why they shouldn't run out of the box with eclipse either, as I believe eclipse has support for Maven too? Have a look at the mvc-showcase project in particular, the build seems to be broken at the moment but they've been constantly updating it lately.

Comment: @Brett Eclipse doesn't offer Maven support out-of-the-box, you need to install the m2eclipse plugin (not a big deal but it's just not there in a fresh install). However, SpringSource Tools Suite (STS), which is a distro of Eclipse tailored for Spring development, includes it by default. That's why I mentioned it here.

Answer (score 9):

I am also started to learn Spring 3.0 and i am not getting any help means any tutorials. but i find this site http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc.html and its very help full for start up development. but still i am finding another example so that i come to know more about it 
if anybody knows some example in spring 3.0 then please provide me.

Thanks
Dhrumil Shah

Answer (score 2):

These days, I think the easiest way to find out how to set up a spring application is by trying out [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). It may not be what you finally end up using when coding your project but it shows you exactly how to setup a Spring MVC web app.

Answer (score 2):

I've also been looking all over for a full Spring MVC 3.0 tutorial with Eclipse that I could follow and haven't had too much luck in my research. The closest and most helpful example that I could find is here: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html. This is also a maven project, but I was able to move some things around in my Dynamic Web Project within Eclipse and at least get the initial page to come up. Currently, I'm having issues with spring finding my controller class, but I think that's a part of changing the configuration files to meet my project needs. But try it and I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I found these tutorials really helpful:

http://krams915.blogspot.ch/p/tutorials.html

I wanted to use REST and MongoDB and followed following tutorial with success:

http://krams915.blogspot.ch/2012/01/spring-mvc-31-implement-crud-with_4739.html

I hope it helps. I know how you feel :) Had the same issues. But it's worth sticking with Spring and learning it. It's a great framework once you know it.

Personally I made not so good experiences using Spring Roo. It can help you maybe a little bit for investigation how to setup a project but if you are new to Aspect Oriented Development you'll have a hard time figuring out what Spring Roo does. It can help you to setup a project really fast and easy but if you don't understand what's behind the facade it's hard working with it. This is not really for a beginner and no necessity for any project. But Aspect Oriented Development is worth wile learning and can be very useful to avoid boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

Another route might be use appfuse, specifically using maven to generate the application template code from the appfuse archetype. E.g. [this link](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart).

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference in Spring 2.5 and Spring 3.x, Spring 3 or later introduces Annotations based bean wiring and dependency injection. 
The nice step by step tutorial i found is http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial