# Where can I get the petclinic sample app for Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring

Docs,forums etc. keeps referencing the Spring petclinic example. Where can I get this for spring 3.0.x ? (it seems not to be bundled with spring-framework-3.0.3.RELEASE-with-docs.zip)

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting started with Spring 3 Web MVC - Setting everything up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260552/getting-started-with-spring-3-web-mvc-setting-everything-up), [How to run Spring 3.0 PetClinic in tomcat with Hibernate backed JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536292/how-to-run-spring-3-0-petclinic-in-tomcat-with-hibernate-backed-jpa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/) it is!!!

Comment: That is not for version 3.0 is it?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-in-3.0-samples

Answer (score 1):

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

it is now on Github (and based on Spring 4):
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic