# Creating WebApplication with Database Access in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sybase

I have to create a simple WebApplication with Java which shows a Login Dialog and after it shows some textfields, gets some Data out of a Database (Sybase) do something with it and insert a new record to the database. Now I am looking for a good tutorial, which explains me, how to setup the needed environment and shows me the start for creating a WebApplication with Java. Can anyone give me some good links to such tutorials? - Many Thanks.

Comment: jw - are you using Sybase for a particular reason?

Comment: @csjohn - There is already an existing Sybase-Database from an ERP-System and I have to read some data out of this existing Database.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- [BalusC blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/) - more JSF focused but has every thing . Does not use Spring.
2- [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) great starter application plus tutorials uses spring.
3- [LULU](http://www.lulu.com/product/file-download/tutorial-java-maven-2-eclipse-jsf/1603040) - Interestingly does not have community presence or atleast not with same name.Uses Spring
4- [Java Passion](http://www.javapassion.com/) - But not free but very well worth it. I have been member since it was free and now pay annual subscription every year.Not based on spring but does have spring for those who are interested.
5- [Spring Roo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdaidK2JhqI) this is youtube link but you can google as well popular but not my personal choice.

6- [Jboss](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/J2EETutorialTips) - This is tips link which has further links.Does not use spring and wish they will all die (pun intended and hope not)
7- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html) No spring and probably best for any starter

I can go on and on but this should be enough . Also I have a feeling that this question might be closed as soon as people in North-Western Hemisphere wake up :)

Comment: Can You please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130366/taking-input-variables-from-a-tablehtml-and-supply-the-values-as-a-variable-na

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look at using Spring (which seems very popular these days) maybe you should check out this question:
[Getting started with Spring 3 Web MVC - Setting everything up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260552/getting-started-with-spring-3-web-mvc-setting-everything-up)

Answer (score 0):

[Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) is what you need. It provides the simplest way to create a web application. Starting with [hello world application](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/firstapp) you'll find another manuals and samples that will help you to achieve your goals.