# How to handle JSON response in java

Tags: java, json, rest

I have requirement to handle json response and it is coming by rest service GET Method call.
    I already have looked solutions from these links:-

http://www.journaldev.com/2315/java-json-processing-api-example-tutorial

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/

but it is not fulfill my requirements because it is small and static. I am keeping my json response in below:-

```
`<!--json response start -->

   {
    "HotelListResponse": {
        "cachedSupplierResponse": {
            "@cachedTime": "0",
            "@candidatePreptime": "111",
            "@matchedCurrency": "true",
            "@matchedLocale": "true",
            "@otherOverheadTime": "4",
            "@supplierRequestNum": "211",
            "@supplierResponseNum": "20",
            "@supplierResponseTime": "405",
            "@tpidUsed": "5001"
        },
        "cacheKey": "302c317:13443ffb599:-7712",
        "cacheLocation": "10.186.168.61:7302",
        "customerSessionId": "0ABAA83D-2C31-7913-4432-FFB599907714",
         "HotelList": {
            "@activePropertyCount": "237",
            "@size": "1",
            "HotelSummary": {
                "@ubsScore": "1867",
                "@order": "0",
                "hotelId": 127092,
                "name": "The Edgewater - A Noble House Hotel",
                "address1": "Pier 67, 2411 Alaskan Way",
                "city": "Seattle",
                "stateProvinceCode": "WA",
                "postalCode": 98121,
                "countryCode": "US",
                "airportCode": "SEA",
                "supplierType": "E",
                "propertyCategory": 1,
                "hotelRating": 4,
                "confidenceRating": 85,
                "amenityMask": 6259019,
                "tripAdvisorRating": 4,
                "tripAdvisorReviewCount": 590,
                "tripAdvisorRatingUrl": "http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/4.0-12345-4.gif",
                "locationDescription": "Near Washington State Convention & Trade Center",
                "shortDescription": "<p><b>Location. </b> <br />The Edgewater - A Noble House Hotel is a business-friendly hotel located in central Seattle, close to Odyssey - The Maritime Discovery Center, Washington State Convention &",
                "highRate": 249,
                "lowRate": 186.75,
                "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
                "latitude": 47.61252,
                "longitude": -122.35013,
                "proximityDistance": 11.898841,
                "proximityUnit": "MI",
                "hotelInDestination": true,
                "thumbNailUrl": "/hotels/1000000/20000/11200/11133/11133_73_t.jpg",
                "deepLink": "http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=55505&hotelID=127092&mode=2&numberOfRooms=2&room-0-adult-total=1&room-0-child-total=1&room-0-child-0-age=3&room-1-adult-total=1&room-1-child-total=1&room-1-child-0-age=5&arrivalMonth=8&arrivalDay=4&departureMonth=8&departureDay=5&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD",
                "RoomRateDetailsList": {
                    "RoomRateDetails": {
                        "roomTypeCode": 1160,
                        "rateCode": 1221260,
                        "maxRoomOccupancy": 2,
                        "quotedRoomOccupancy": 2,
                        "minGuestAge": 0,
                        "roomDescription": "City Lodge - Nonrefundable",
                        "promoId": 200803780,
                        "promoDescription": "7-Day Advance Purchase Special (Nonrefundable)",
                        "currentAllotment": 10,
                        "propertyAvailable": true,
                        "propertyRestricted": false,
                        "expediaPropertyId": 11133,
                        "rateKey": "f3525aff-9f4d-4d92-bc1c-144628fcaa30",
                        "nonRefundable": true,
                        "RateInfos": {
                            "@size": "1",
                            "RateInfo": {
                                "@rateChange": "false",
                                "@promo": "true",
                                "@priceBreakdown": "true",
                                "RoomGroup": {
                                    "Room": [
                                        {
                                            "numberOfAdults": 1,
                                            "numberOfChildren": 1,
                                            "childAges": 3
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "numberOfAdults": 1,
                                            "numberOfChildren": 1,
                                            "childAges": 5
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                                    "@commissionableUsdTotal": "373.5",
                                    "@total": "441.74",
                                    "@surchargeTotal": "68.24",
                                    "@nightlyRateTotal": "373.5",
                                    "@averageBaseRate": "249.0",
                                    "@averageRate": "186.75",
                                    "@maxNightlyRate": "186.75",
                                    "@currencyCode": "USD",
                                    "NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
                                        "@size": "1",
                                        "NightlyRate": {
                                            "@promo": "true",
                                            "@rate": "186.75",
                                            "@baseRate": "249.0"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Surcharges": {
                                        "@size": "1",
                                        "Surcharge": {
                                            "@amount": "68.24",
                                            "@type": "TaxAndServiceFee"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so here I am getting dynamic response based on my rest url call so how do I set this json response to my pojo.

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance. 
`

Comment: What do you mean by static/dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework to handle all that for you; a great one is Spring.
Have a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)
Here is [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2260552/1183010) to get you jump-started.

example from link above:

create a `Controller` to handle REST calls (changed to demonstrate json use):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc/brands")
public class JSONController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name, @RequestBody JsonNode json) {
        // do stuff with the json request body (its is jackson)
        JsonNode test= json.get("test");

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});

        return shop;

    }
}

// you could use jQuery to perform a REST call to your new controller:
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "[your server]/kfc/brands",
    data: {"test": "json value"},
    success: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) lib. It converts **json** to **pojo** and **pojo** to **json**.

Comment: Hi, Thank you , it is working . Now I have only one problem , my json response have key like @cachedTime etc  and java pojo not support to use identifier start with @ , So please let me know How to set the value of this type of key in my pojo.

Comment: For me it's very strange to use a key with '@' prefix. Are sure that you that need prefix?

Comment: Some thing misunderstanding here ,Now I am trying to clear it :- This @ prefix is already available on json response but I want to map this json field to my pojo field nothing else.For ex:-                      (1) @size is a json filed  (2) and size is a java identifier in my pojo  , now what I need to do to map these two field in my gson .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a schema for the JSON response then [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#using-jsonschema2pojo-within-your-java-project-embedded) would be a good tool to use. It works in a similar way that JAXB does for XML, in that it generates pojos at build time based on the schema, which you can then use at compile time.

If there isn't a schema but you are confident on the format, you could always [generate the schema yourself](http://www.jsonschema.net/).